When running the Flask app, the output showing it's running on localhost isn't printed in the terminal; it's redirected to the log file
 * Serving Flask app 'app'
 * Debug mode: on

These lines appear in the command line.
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
Press CTRL+C to quit
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 458-677-350

These lines are printed in the log file.
Also note that this issue occurs only when I add this import:
from .utils.predict import MakePrediction

I want to see the complete Flask app startup messages in the command line, even with the from .utils.predict import MakePrediction import.
what to do to solve this issue ?

We would have to see your predict.py module to know why logging behavior would change

Most likely that module is modifying your general log settings. That is something a library should do in rare situations only.

Import from .utils.predict import MakePrediction before importing anything from flask module

@JohnnyCheesecutter your method didn't worked.
